# P-th derivative on $\mathbb{R^n}$ and an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Recall**. Define higher-order differentials. Let $p \geq 1,$ let $V$ be open in $\mathbf{R}^{n},$ let $\boldsymbol{a} \in V,$ and let
 $f: V \rightarrow \mathbf{R} .$ We shall say that $f$ has a pth-order total differential at $a$ if and only if
the $(p-1)$ st-order partial derivatives of $f$ exist on $V$ and are differentiable at $a$, in
which case we shall use the notation

$$D^{(p)} f(\boldsymbol{\alpha}, \boldsymbol{h}):=\sum_{i_{1}=1}^{n} \cdots \sum_{i_{p}=1}^{n} \frac{\partial^{p} f}{\partial x_{i_{1}} \ldots \partial x_{i_{p}}}(\boldsymbol{a}) h_{i_{1}} \cdots h_{i_{p}}, \quad \boldsymbol{h}=\left(h_{1}, \ldots, h_{n}\right) \in \mathbf{R}^{n}$$

**My question is**: Suppose $f$ has partial derivatives up to order $r$ at $p$. Show that there is a $C>0$ such that for each $1\leq k \leq r$ and $h\in\mathbb{R^m}$ we have $|D^{(k) }f(p,h)|\leq C|h|^k.$

May you help to show this question? May you give a hint?

Comment: What is k in your inequality?

Comment: k-th derivative

Comment: That is k is natural numbrr

Comment: So you have to prove it for all $k \leq r$?

Comment: Ahhh okey. I already know this. Edited question now

Comment: i'm waiting help

Comment: im waiting help

Comment: Edited now.....